# How to build/bundle a package with turborepo?

Tags: vercel, monorepo, turborepo, turbopack

I am creating a CLI application using **turborepo** and **typescript**.

I've created the monorepo using the official new turborepo command.

"x" is one of my "apps". It has a `src/index.ts` file that says:

`console.log('hello world')`

But when I run `turbo build`, on the "x" directory or on the monorepo directory, **nothing is generated** (I don't get any errors either).

What am I missing?